# How to turn old iPad on after not being used for years

Tags: ipad

So I had bought an iPad about 5 years ago (iPad 1), and I found it lying on a shelf, and I thought: why not use it? But it doesn't turn on. I let it charge for 16 hours and it still does not turn on. Also, when it is plugged in, the screen turns on (it's just black but you can see its on) for less than a second and then turns back off. Can someone help me turn it on and get it working?

Comment: Not to be a buzzkill but the battery could just be toast. That is a simple replacement for an independent repair shop, Apple may even be able to replace the battery.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the hints & tipps of the web page I added the link at the end of my answer.

I recommend starting with the "hard reset" as this might help if the iPad just got "stuck": 
"perform a hard restart by pressing and holding both the HOME button AND the POWER/SLEEP/WAKE button until the Apple logo appears."

If it is sure that the iPad got charged and you don't see a symbol about "low power", and if the hard reset didn't help it might be necessary to connect the iPad to a Mac or PC with iTunes installed. Please continue with the instructions of the linked page.

If this is not the right direction for you it might be an alternative to just find help either by Apple Tech guys in an Apple Store or in some stores where Apple iOS/iPads is well known stuff...

Here's the link:
http://appletoolbox.com/2014/12/ipad-will-not-turn-fix-dead-device/

Good luck! Fingers crossed.